# Working out totals of jquery calc

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make calculations in real time and that's working fine for each textbox, but I am having trouble make a total of all of them.

In `calculateTotal` I want to generate this total

```
cictotal = ependitureSumTotal - (ependitureSumTotal + reducibsumTotal);
$("#lblTotalcic").html(cictotal.toFixed(2));
```

But it's just giving me a value of zero

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            calculateSum();
            expendureSum();
            reducibleSumCalc();
            calculateTotal();
            //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
            //handler to trigger sum event
            $(".incomeSum").each(function () {

                $(this).keyup(function () {
                    calculateSum();
                    calculateTotal();
                });
            });


            $(".expendureSum").each(function () {

                $(this).keyup(function () {
                    expendureSum();
                    calculateTotal();
                });
            });



            $(".reducibleSum").each(function () {

                $(this).keyup(function () {
                    reducibleSumCalc();
                    calculateTotal();
                });
            });


        });

        function calculateTotal() {
            var ependitureSumTotal = 0;
            $(".incomeSum").each(function () {

                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    ependitureSumTotal += parseFloat(this.value);
                }

            });

            var ependitureSumTotal = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".expendureSum").each(function () {

                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    ependitureSumTotal += parseFloat(this.value);
                }

            });
            var reducibsumTotal = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".reducibleSum").each(function () {

                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    reducibsumTotal += parseFloat(this.value);
                }

            });

            cictotal = ependitureSumTotal - (ependitureSumTotal + reducibsumTotal);
            $("#lblTotalcic").html(cictotal.toFixed(2));


        }
        function calculateSum() {

            var sum = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".incomeSum").each(function () {

                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }

            });
            //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
            $("#sumTotalIncome").html(sum.toFixed(2));


        }

        function expendureSum() {

            var sum = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".expendureSum").each(function () {

                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }

            });
            //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
            $("#expendureTotalSum").html(sum.toFixed(2));


        }


        function reducibleSumCalc() {

            var sum = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".reducibleSum").each(function () {

                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }

            });
            //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
            $("#reducibleSumTotal").html(sum.toFixed(2));


        }



    </script>
```

**Edit 1**

As Suggested I want to calualtate some fields so I have created a small fiddle to demostrate what I want to achieve this is working but i need to no how to minus the totals figures together into a balance label.

**JSFiddle**
**https://jsfiddle.net/fqdeeam6/**

Comment: Please make a fiddle

Comment: @Mojtaba making a fiddle is not a requirment of Stack Over Flow

Comment: Are you trying to keep the requirements? or find an answer? as you see, no one even tried to answer you. Because no one has time to guess your HTML. We are here to help each other. If I am asking you to make a fiddle, it's because I want you to achieve the solution soon

Comment: what the html is self explanity its spans but yes I will make a fiddle then

Comment: @Mojtaba please find enclosed my jsfiddle in the edit1 tag above

Comment: Looka t my answer and let me know if you had any question

Comment: @Mojtaba i left a question under your answer

Comment: Look at the updated answer. I hope you find anything you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsFiddle was not clear and had various errors.

By the way, I have refactored it.

**NOTE:** Whenever you have multi elements with the same class name and you want to bind an event to all of them, you don't need to do it once by once using each. Just bind the event to the class name. like this:

```
$(".incomeSum").keyup(function () {
    calculateSum();
});
```

Here is the full functional code:

```js
function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".incomeSum").each(function () {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $("#sumTotalIncome").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  calculateTotal();
}

function calculateSum2() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".expenses").each(function () {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $("#sumTotalExpenses").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  calculateTotal();
}

function calculateTotal() {
    incomes = +$('#sumTotalIncome').text();
    expenses = +$('#sumTotalExpenses').text();
    $('#totalResult').text((incomes - expenses).toFixed(2));
}


$(document).ready(function () {
  calculateSum();
  calculateSum2();
  calculateTotal();

  $(".incomeSum").keyup(function () {
    calculateSum();
  });

  $(".expenses").keyup(function () {
    calculateSum2();
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="partnerearningcics" class="col-md-7 form-control-label sidesthin-right">Incomes:</label>
  <div class="col-md-5 sidestight-left sidesthin-right">
    <input id="WagesSpouseNet" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid incomeSum" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 sidestight-left sidesthin-right">
    <input id="WagesSpouseNet2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid incomeSum" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<strong><span id="sumTotalIncome" class="sumResult">0</span><hr><strong>


<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="partnerearningcics" class="col-md-7 form-control-label sidesthin-right">Expenses:</label>
  <div class="col-md-5 sidestight-left sidesthin-right">
    <input id="WagesSpouseNet" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid expenses" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 sidestight-left sidesthin-right">
    <input id="WagesSpouseNet2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid expenses" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<strong><span id="sumTotalExpenses" class="sumResult">0</span></strong>
  
<p><strong>Total: <span id="totalResult">0</span></strong></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I no its not precies I no jquery expert like yourself but what I must do is minus another value from another caluation like i showed in the code is there anyway of doing that  see way i had that other bit where i minus the expnses from total how would i do that ?

Comment: @dave, your fiddle does not have any other value. I still don't know what should be calculated. Please provide enough data. Then, I can help you.

Comment: im wanting another function simlar to above and I am wanting to subtract that value from sum total income how would i do that

Comment: @dave, you can't ask your requests step by step. You have to post a clear question to get a clear answer. You are changing the requirements every time.

Comment: Thank you for your help mate when i think of it now its logical to go out to the span.

Comment: @dave, no problem. Please post your different questions separately